# Why declaration of nested datatype in Haskell invokes error?

Tags: haskell

```
> data Seq a = Nil | Cons a (Seq (a,a))

<hint>:1:1: parse error on input `data'
```

so this is a piece of haskell declaring a nested datatype of a binary tree, 
using this version:

http://tryhaskell.org/#9

Comment: A datatype declaration requires the keyword **data**.

Comment: Oh that's a typo, updated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably an small deficiency in TryHaskell, unfortunately. Here's (a recent) GHCi

```
Prelude> data Seq a = Nil | Cons a (Seq (a,a))
Prelude> :i Seq
data Seq a = Nil | Cons a (Seq (a, a))
    -- Defined at <interactive>:2:6
```

Comment: Maybe not a bug. TryHaskell is not designed to be a full-blown programming environment. It just needs to support material covered by the lessons. `data` is not covered (yet?)

Comment: Note that support of data declaration in GHCi is extremely recent, in the past, you declared your data and class in a file, GHCi was reserved to expression (basically a big IO do-block, thus let-declarations are allowed, pure expressions are wrapped in print).

Comment: Both true. I'll reword my answer.